Can someone that died upon shirk go to Jannah?
Now in Islam we know shirk is the sin that will take you to jahannam
My question is if someone dies upon shirk (Hindu, believing Jesus is god, Trinity. Etc) but they never heard of Islam or got the wrong message of Islam due to the media.
Can they have a chance for Jannah? Since Allah doesn’t punish someone unless they receive a warner

There are creedal differences on this. The Athari and Ashari creeds have a very similar opinion where the person who is ignorant of Islam and dies in ignorance, will either get tested on the day of judgement or get jannah. As for the Maturidis, the opinion is that those who indulge in shirk, even if they never heard even a single word of Islam, will go to jahannum due to it because their fitrah should have been a source of guidance for them yet they declined. They also state that there are countless example of monotheists who never heard of Islam but found it on their own.
